# Book reference for linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, book-recommendation

I have studied linear algebra during my bachelor's degree and Master's degree. I know the subject but not up-to the mark I want to understand linear algebra through linear transformation and specially the portion where we start decomposition of a vector space through a linear transformation. Like Jordan canonical form, primary decomposition theorem etc. There are so many great books available but I am unable to choose which one suit to my problem. I have gone through Hoffman and kunje and Axler earlie. I found Hoffman so much time taking it builds topic slowly. But whatever portion I studied from that book till linear transformation it was amazing.I want to know whether I should go through these books again or is there a text which I can go through for second course in linear algebra?

Comment: Did you watch 3blue1brown videos on linear algebra? https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDPD3MizzM2xVFitgF8hE_ab

Comment: Yaa I watched these videos are really nice and intuitive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prerequisites/Books for A First Course in Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43930/prerequisites-books-for-a-first-course-in-linear-algebra)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I took linear algebra at Berkeley in the late 80's, Bill Jacob taught from his book, which was still in manuscript form.  He was quite good, and I would recommend the book.  I looked him up recently,  and he is now head of the department at UCSB. He is quite accomplished...

Then there is Gilbert Strang's book,  *Linear Algebra and Its Applications*, i think it is called.  As the title suggests,  it has a decidedly applied feel.  I think it's pretty good.  Btw, he's a professor at MIT.

There was a popular book by an author named Anton, i believe it was.

As you mentioned,  there are quite a few.

Finally, i believe my former advisor Peter Petersen at UCLA has a book on the subject.  Though I can't tell you anything about it's focus or approach, it should be pretty good.

Oh, and one last one:  P R Halmos wrote a book called *Finite Dimensional Vector Spaces* which is supposed to be pretty good...

Just to name a few...

Sorry I can't remember for sure if they cover the topics you mentioned;   but I have a feeling they are pretty standard.

Comment: Actually in strang's book he has used matrices. I want to go through a book which describe linear algebra through linear transformation and then discover the properties of matrices. As Hoffman or Axler they have not focused much on matrices..thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 9):

My favorite Linear Algebra textbook is Katsumi Nomizu's *Fundamentals of Linear Algebra*. It covers those topics that you are interested in.

Comment: Why a -1? This answers the question.

Comment: @Paul I suppose that this was meant as an attack on me, rather than a criticism os my answer. I say this because at the same time that I got this downvote, I got another one to [my answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2863387/446262)

Comment: Life on the internet I suppose.

Comment: +1 to compensate idiocy and since the book indeed addresses those topics.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Thank you. That was a nice gesture.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. If I upvote it is not working. It is showing me some message.  May be I have pressed that many times.

Comment: @PrakashNainwal You will not be able to upvote until your reputation reaches $15$.